# Socat download - what file to choose for installation? Windows

Tags: socat

My antivirus program prohibits the download of netcat. So, I have chosen to download Socat through Winzip. However, I have no clue whatsoever of which file I should use to install the tool... Or if it's already installed, when it's locally downloaded?

I have approx. 20 different packages downloaded in the zip file.. not sure which one to choose for installation.

I have tried this:
Get the tarball and extract it:

```
tar xzf socat.tar.gz
cd socat-1.7.3.0
./configure
make
su
make install    # installs socat, filan, and procan in /usr/local/bin
```

But it cant find tar...

All help is appreciated

Operating system windows 64-bit

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You use Windows, so you need to install the Cygwin.com suite, which btw might contain a ready-to-use Socat package.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).